# Prevent Spark from copying JAR dependencies to `work/` folder for each executor node

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to prevent Spark from automatically copying the JAR files specified via `--jars` in the spark-submit command to the `work/` folder for each executor node?

My `spark-submit` command specifies all the JAR dependencies for the job like so

```
spark-submit \
  --master <master> \
  --jars local:/<jar1-path>,local:/<jar2-path>... \
  <application-jar> \
  <arguments>
```

These JAR paths live on a distributed filesystem that is available in the same location on all the cluster nodes.

Now, according to [the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management):

> Note that JARs and files are copied to the working directory for each SparkContext on the executor nodes. This can use up a significant amount of space over time and will need to be cleaned up.

The last sentence is absolutely true. My JAR dependencies need to include some multi-gigabyte model files, and when I deploy my Spark job over 100 nodes, you can imagine that having 100 copies of these files wastes huge amounts of disk space, not to mention the time it takes to copy them.

Is there a way to prevent Spark from copying the dependencies?  I'm not sure I understand why it needs to copy them in the first place, **given that the JARS are accessible from each cluster node via the same path**. There should not be a need to keep distinct copies of each JAR in each node's working directory.

That same Spark documentation mentions that

> **local:** - a URI starting with local:/ is expected to exist as a local file on each worker node. This means that no network IO will be incurred, and works well for large files/JARs that are pushed to each worker, or shared via NFS, GlusterFS, etc.

...which is exactly how I'm referencing the JARS in the spark-submit command.

So, can Spark be prevented from copying all JARS specified via `local:/...` to the working directory of each cluster node?  If so, how? If not, is there a reason why this copying must happen?

Edit: clarified that copies are per-node (not per-executor)

Comment: Spark makes one copy of all dependencies per node under working dir. It is not one per executor. This working directory is cleaned up after the job is complete. Why do you want to clean the dir explicitly when it does not exists after the job terminates ?

Comment: You are correct, it's one copy per node. However, even this one copy-per-node uses a huge amount of disk space (and the time it takes to make the copy) when the JAR dependencies are *very* large (multi-gigabyte) and the number of nodes is large (100+).  It's not a matter of wanting to clean it when the job terminates (I already know the Spark settings to enable that), it's a matter of asking Spark not to make the copies in the first place.  It's unclear to me why the copies are needed on a shared filesystem.